# How to group the result of array in two categories in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, grouping

I have data here:

```
Array
(
[1] => Array
    (
        [SiteID] => 1
        [OwnerAID] => 1

    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [SiteID] => 3
        [OwnerAID] => 1

    )

[6] => Array
     (
        [SiteID] => 6
        [OwnerAID] => 2

     )
    )
```

Now, I need to group the `OwnerAID` into two categories: the first one is `OwnerAID` owning only one `SiteID` and the second one is `OwnerAID` owning more than 1 `SiteID`.

I've tried to make a program and do some research, but the output of my code is wrong.

Please see my code:

```
       public function groupIndividualAndAggregateSites()
    {

    $arrays = array();
        foreach($this->combined as $key => $key_value)
        {
            $SiteID = "";

        if ($SiteID == "") {

            $SiteID=array($key_value['SiteID']); }

           else {
                   $SiteID = array_merge((array)$SiteID, (array)$key_value['SiteID']);

                   $SiteID = array_unique($SiteID);

                }

       } if ($SiteID != "") {

       $arrays = array('AID'=>$key_value['AID'], 'Sites' => $SiteID);
     }
        print_r($arrays);

    }
```

The result should be shown like this:

```
 Array( 
        [1] => Array

      ( [Sites] => Array ([0] => 1, [1] => 3)))

 Array( 
        [2] => Array

      ( [Sites] => Array ([0] => [6]))
```

Comment: So, for the avoidance of doubt, the keys of the original outermost array do not need to appear in the resulting array?

Comment: Yes eggyal. Thanks for the concern.

Comment: Ok, I'm done with my answer, I hope you got the Idea.

Comment: Hi Gundars, Thank you so much, it's a great help, but if ever I will have little bit question in your code,I will tell you. Thanks again.

Comment: @Mic Glad I could help. If you got what you needed, accept my answer by clicking the V mark next to it. PS - I fully encourage you to ask questions about it. Thats how we learn :)

Comment: Hi sir Gundars, sure, your answer was the closest from the result that I want to achieved but if you don't mind sir, could you pls help me to format the printing of array of what I wanted. Pls review my question again. Thank you sir and more power.

Comment: I simply don't think your desired output is semantic, so I prefer mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should go for is array:

```
$owners = array(
owner_1 => SiteID1, // int Only one site
owner_2 => array (SiteID2,SiteID3), // array Multiple sites
);
```

and later use the array $owners like:

```
echo (is_array($owners[$owner_1]) ? 'Has multiple sites' : 'has one site';
```

Thats the basic idea of small memory footprint.

Example, not tested.

```
public function groupIndividualAndAggregateSites() {
  $owners = array();
  foreach($this->combined as $key => $value) {
    $owner_id = $value['OwnerAID'];
    $site_id = $value['SiteID'];

    if(array_key_exists($owner_id,$owners)) {
      // He has one or more sites already?
      if(is_array($owners[$owner_id]){
        array_push($owners[$owner_id],$site_id);
      } else {
      // User already has one site. Lets make an array instead and add old and new siteID
        $old_site_id = $owners[$owner_id];
        $owners[$owner_id] = array($old_site_id,$owner_id);
      }
    } else {
      $owners[$owner_id] = $site_id;
    }
return $owners;    
}
```

Comment: Hi Sir Gundars, there something wrong with the printing of arrays, but I got your idea, I learn something new,I need to format the array in the kind of result what I wanted.(Please see my question again) May you please help me sir.Thank you so much sir.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is loop over your initial array, appending each `OwnerAID` to the relevant output subarray as determined by the `SiteID`:

```
$output = array(1=>array(), 2=>array());
foreach ($original as $v) $output[$v['SiteID'] == 1 ? 1 : 2][] = $v['OwnerAID'];
```

Here I am using the following features:

- [`array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array.php) initialisation function;
- [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) control structure;
- [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary);
- `$array[$key]` addressing;
- `$array[]` pushing.